# Is there unit tests for STL containers?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, stl

Is there ready unit tests for testing if STL containers are working correctly, something that was used by compiler creators?

I'm making a simple port of the STL in C and need to test the data structures and thought that STL unit tests already existed, but didn't find anything

Comment: Here are some for STLPort: https://github.com/karottc/STLport-5.2.1/tree/master/test/unit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there unit tests for STL containers?

[STL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library) does not exist anymore. Read the C++11 standard [n3337](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/master/papers/n3337.pdf) and see this [C++ reference website](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp). Consider also using [Boost](https://boost.org/).

Both recent [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) and recent [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/) provide testsuites for the standard C++ [containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) library, whose implementation is practically tied to the compiler (because of [compiler optimizations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler))

> I'm making a simple port of the STL in C

Then look -at least for inspiration- into [Glib](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk-tutorial/stable/c2023.html) (from [GTK](https://gtk.org/)) and [SGLIB](http://sglib.sourceforge.net/). I tend to think that you could use one of them. Given the complexity of the standard C++ library, I believe you won't be able to make from scratch in just a few weeks a *simple port* of it to C if you care about efficiency. Look also into [MILEPOST GCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MILEPOST_GCC) and read [this paper](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/212094.212124) then [*Artificial Beings: the conscience of a conscious machine*](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/9780470611791) ISBN:9781848211018 for some interesting insights.

Otherwise, be sure to read [*Introduction to algorithms*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms)

Notice that with some care, you usually  can write in C++ a library callable from C (use `extern "C"` appropriately and systematically). A good example is of course [libgccjit](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/) (which you could consider using, for some [partial evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_evaluation) based approaches: you might generate specialized machine code suited to particular instances of your problems).

If you code your generic container library in C, consider using [Frama-C](https://frama-c.com/) on it, and with a recent GCC, compile it [with](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) all warnings and static analysis options. You might even consider writing your [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) to check that users of your library are using it correctly.

See also the European [DECODER](https://www.decoder-project.eu/) project.

Comment: wow, thanks for the awesome links! However I mistyped in my question: I'm just implementing some standard containers (list, vector, deque) and basic iterators, but a happy mistake with all the new knowledge! (sorry for the bad english)

Comment: What does "STL does not exist anymore" means"? Is there any offisial statement about that? Has it been removed from the language, and if not, why did you feel it was important to mention it? None of your links answer this question.